# Magento: error to see special characters in store view

Tags: magento, view, character

i've little problem.

I've some store view and all is ok.
Now i've add 1 new store view, but on this i've problem to see in backend

For example:  Novità --> I see on this store: NovitÃ

è --> Ã¨

etc.

How i can solve?

Thanks
Luca

Comment: How did you create MySQL database?

Comment: What locale have you set?

Comment: have you tried : The solution for these problems is to add

AddDefaultCharset Off
in the .htaccess file in the magento root directory. If you still have problems, ramp up to this:

AddDefaultCharset UTF-8

Comment: mmm, but how is possible that some store view work and this not? I've inserted equal Locale of correct store.